# What percentage of the articles are defective but are considered as if not by both inspectors?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems, geometric-probability

### The exercise says like this:

> Two inspectors $A$ and $B$ independently inspected the same batch of
>   articles. 4% of items are defective. The examination showed that:
>
> - 5% of items are considered defective by $A$.
> - 6% of items are considered defective by $B$.
> - 2% of items are correctly considered defective by $A$.
> - 3% of items are correctly considered defective by $B$.
> - 4% are considered defective by both $A$ and $B$.
> - 1% are considered correctly defective by both $A$ and $B$.
>
> $a)$ Construct a Venn diagram, which shows the percentages of the
>   items in the 8 possible disjoint classes, motivated by the
>   classification of the inspectors and the actual classification of the
>   articles.
>
> $b)$ What percentage of the articles are defective but are considered
>   as if not by both inspectors?

### **And I have something like this:**

> [image]*($C$ is "correctly
>   defective")*

**So, the answer means $C∩(A∪B)^c$, the blue zone**?

Comment: There's something wrong with your Venn diagram. B only considers 6% of items defective, but you've got a total of 9 in that circle.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have fixed it. Your answer is equal to $C∩(A∪B)^c$, the blue zone?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4% of items are actually defective. 1% are considered so by both A and B; that leaves 3% that are correctly considered defective by at most one inspector. A correctly considers a total of 2% defective; that means 1% beyond the overlap. B correctly considers a total of 3% defective; that means 2% beyond the overlap. That adds up to 3% beyond the overlap that are correctly considered defective by at least one inspector. There was only 3% left over; that means that there's nothing left to be defective but not considered defective by either inspector. So, 0%.